# Spring Boot and Swagger

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a spring boot 1.5.1RELEASE app that I am trying to use Swagger with.  I added the dependencies:

```
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.5.0'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.5.0'compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1RELEASE)
```

And then a /config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {    
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                        .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build();           
    }    

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                        .title("My API Documentation ")
                        .description("Swagger API Documentation provided for your viewing pleasure")
                        .version("1.0")
                        .build();
    }
}
```

I have a GET endpoint

```
@Api(value = "/words", description = "Words API", produces = "application/json")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/words")
public class WordsController {

@ApiOperation(value = "getAllWords", nickname = "getAllWords",
              response = ResponseEntity.class, httpMethod = "GET")
@ApiResponses(value = {
                @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = ResponseEntity.class),
                @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")
                })
@RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity getAllWords() {
...}
```

But when I access my api at `http://localhost:3000/swagger-ui.html` (I have my server configured to run on port 3000 I get only the green swagger bar
[image]

I am building this off several tutorials, but I can't see why my Swagger documentation is not being presented

Answer (score 0):

Seems its an issue in your configuration class,Try with below swagger configuration class

```
import static com.google.common.base.Predicates.or;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.regex;
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

/**
 * Sample Swgger config.
 *
 * @author Eranga
 */
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class MySwaggerConfig  {

    /**
     * Grouping only words api end points.
     *
     * @return the docket
     */
    @Bean
    public Docket myApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select().paths(myApiPath()).build();
    }

    /**
     * Filtering only media activity api end points.
     *
     * @return the predicate
     */
    private Predicate<String> myApiPath() {
        return or(regex("//words.*"));
    }

    /**
     * Api info.
     *
     * @return the api info
     */
    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("My API title")
                .description(
                        "my Api desc")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://erangakodikara.blogspot.com/").contact("Eranga")
                .license("Apache License Version 2.0")
                .licenseUrl("https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/master/LICENSE").version("2.0").build();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I have it fixed by moving my SwaggerConfig into my Main Class, so for some reason this @Configuration is not being picked up